# What are the right settings to connect to spark cluster remotely on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark

I have a spark cluster on AWS with all ports open and I have my driver programming running locally on my laptop. I get the following trace and I am not sure how to fix it? I believe my driver program can connect to master because of the following settings

```
export SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS="52.44.36.224"
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=6
```

However my driver program running locally on my laptop may not be able to connect to worker/executor directly because AWS Spark cluster return private ip which are not accessible outside of AWS so I am not sure how to fix it?

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/09/04 01:22:17 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.0.0
16/09/04 01:22:17 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/09/04 01:22:18 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: kantkodali
16/09/04 01:22:18 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: kantkodali
16/09/04 01:22:18 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
16/09/04 01:22:18 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
16/09/04 01:22:18 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(kantkodali); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(kantkodali); groups with modify permissions: Set()
16/09/04 01:22:18 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 55091.
16/09/04 01:22:18 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/09/04 01:22:18 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/09/04 01:22:18 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /private/var/folders/_6/lfxt933j3bd_xhq0m7dwm8s00000gn/T/blockmgr-cc8a4985-f9c0-4c1a-b17f-876e146cbd87
16/09/04 01:22:18 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 2004.6 MB
16/09/04 01:22:18 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/09/04 01:22:19 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/09/04 01:22:19 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://192.168.0.191:4040
16/09/04 01:22:19 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://52.44.36.224:7077...
16/09/04 01:22:19 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /52.44.36.224:7077 after 89 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
16/09/04 01:22:19 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20160904082232-0001
16/09/04 01:22:19 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20160904082232-0001/0 on worker-20160904003146-172.31.3.246-40675 (172.31.3.246:40675) with 2 cores
16/09/04 01:22:19 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20160904082232-0001/0 on hostPort 172.31.3.246:40675 with 2 cores, 1024.0 MB RAM
16/09/04 01:22:19 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20160904082232-0001/1 on worker-20160904003205-172.31.3.245-35631 (172.31.3.245:35631) with 2 cores
16/09/04 01:22:19 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20160904082232-0001/1 on hostPort 172.31.3.245:35631 with 2 cores, 1024.0 MB RAM
16/09/04 01:22:19 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 55093.
16/09/04 01:22:19 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 192.168.0.191:55093
16/09/04 01:22:19 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.0.191, 55093)
16/09/04 01:22:19 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.0.191:55093 with 2004.6 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.0.191, 55093)
16/09/04 01:22:19 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20160904082232-0001/0 is now RUNNING
16/09/04 01:22:19 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.0.191, 55093)
16/09/04 01:22:19 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20160904082232-0001/1 is now RUNNING
16/09/04 01:22:19 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
16/09/04 01:22:20 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: start at Consumer.java:41
16/09/04 01:22:20 INFO DAGScheduler: Registering RDD 1 (start at Consumer.java:41)
16/09/04 01:22:20 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (start at Consumer.java:41) with 20 output partitions
16/09/04 01:22:20 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 1 (start at Consumer.java:41)
16/09/04 01:22:20 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List(ShuffleMapStage 0)
16/09/04 01:22:20 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List(ShuffleMapStage 0)
16/09/04 01:22:20 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ShuffleMapStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at start at Consumer.java:41), which has no missing parents
16/09/04 01:22:20 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.1 KB, free 2004.6 MB)
16/09/04 01:22:20 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2001.0 B, free 2004.6 MB)
16/09/04 01:22:20 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 192.168.0.191:55093 (size: 2001.0 B, free: 2004.6 MB)
16/09/04 01:22:20 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1012
16/09/04 01:22:20 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 50 missing tasks from ShuffleMapStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at start at Consumer.java:41)
16/09/04 01:22:20 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 50 tasks
16/09/04 01:22:35 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
16/09/04 01:22:50 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
16/09/04 01:23:05 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
16/09/04 01:23:20 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
16/09/04 01:23:35 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
16/09/04 01:23:50 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
16/09/04 01:24:05 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
16/09/04 01:24:20 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
16/09/04 01:24:20 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20160904082232-0001/1 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
16/09/04 01:24:20 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20160904082232-0001/1 removed: Command exited with code 1
16/09/04 01:24:20 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 1 requested
16/09/04 01:24:20 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 1
16/09/04 01:24:20 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20160904082232-0001/2 on worker-20160904003205-172.31.3.245-35631 (172.31.3.245:35631) with 1 cores
16/09/04 01:24:20 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20160904082232-0001/2 on hostPort 172.31.3.245:35631 with 1 cores, 1024.0 MB RAM
16/09/04 01:24:20 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20160904082232-0001/3 on worker-20160904003146-172.31.3.246-40675 (172.31.3.246:40675) with 1 cores
16/09/04 01:24:20 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20160904082232-0001/3 on hostPort 172.31.3.246:40675 with 1 cores, 1024.0 MB RAM
```

Comment: Where are the ports open ? In the security group of the Spark Cluster?

Comment: All ports are open. I opened it for all ports because I want to make things work first

Comment: Set Up an SSH Tunnel to the Master Node Using Local Port Forwarding.